# delphi Cipher-based message authentication code (CMAC)

Tags: delphi

I must add CMAC signing to a `TBytes` array.

Is there any library or class to do this?

I searched Google but didn't find anything except some C code that works, but I can't translate this to Delphi because there are some specific libraries that it uses.

```c
/////CMAC HASH KEY
uint8_t hash_key[32]={  0x60,0x3d,0xeb,0x10,
                        0x15,0xca,0x71,0xbe,
                        0x2b,0x73,0xae,0xf0,
                        0x85,0x7d,0x77,0x81,
                        0x1f,0x35,0x2c,0x07,
                        0x3b,0x61,0x08,0xd7,
                        0x2d,0x98,0x10,0xa3,
                        0x09,0x14,0xdf,0xf4};
///CMAC FUNCTION                        
void cmac (uint8_t message_len,uint8_t message_buf[],uint8_t output_Tag[16])
{
    unsigned char mac_main_message[21*16]={0};
    uint8_t mac_main_k[16]={0};
    uint8_t mac_iv_k[16]={0};
    uint8_t mac_xor_k[16]={0};
    uint8_t mac_xor_k_final[16]={0};
    uint8_t mac_tag[16]={0};
            
    uint8_t k1_subkey[16]={0};
    uint8_t k2_subkey[16]={0};
    uint8_t k1_subkey_shift[16]={0};

    uint8_t active_subkey=0;

    uint8_t l_list[16]={0};
    uint8_t l_list_shift[16]={0};
    int mcntr;
    uint8_t rb128=0x87;
    uint8_t const_zero [16]={00,00,00,00,
                             00,00,00,00,
                             00,00,00,00,
                             00,00,00,00   
                        };
    
    uint8_t taqsim_len;
    aes_key_schedule_128(hash_key,hash_key_me);
    aes_encrypt_128(hash_key_me,const_zero,l_list);

    
    ///shift l <<1
    for(mcntr=0 ;mcntr <16;mcntr++)
    {
     l_list_shift[mcntr]=(l_list[mcntr]<<1)&0xFE;
     if(mcntr!=15)
     {l_list_shift[mcntr]|=(l_list[mcntr+1]>>7)&0x01;}
    }
    ///generate k1
    if(((l_list[0]>>7)&0x01)== 0 )//MSB l 0
    {
        memcpy(k1_subkey,l_list_shift,16);
    }
    else //MSB l 1
    {
        l_list_shift[15]^=rb128;
        memcpy(k1_subkey,l_list_shift,16);   
    }
   
        //shift k1 <<1
    for(mcntr=0 ;mcntr <16;mcntr++)
    {
     k1_subkey_shift[mcntr]=(k1_subkey[mcntr]<<1)&0xFE;
     if(mcntr!=15)
     {k1_subkey_shift[mcntr]|=(k1_subkey[mcntr+1]>>7)&0x01;}
    }
    /////generate k2
    if(((k1_subkey[0]>>7)&0x01)== 0 )//MSB k1 0
    {
        memcpy(k2_subkey,k1_subkey_shift,16);
    }
    else //MSB l 1
    {
        k1_subkey_shift[15]^=rb128;
        memcpy(k2_subkey,k1_subkey_shift,16);   
    }
    ////*****************************************cbCmac
    if(message_len%16==0)
    {
        memcpy(mac_main_message,message_buf,message_len);
        active_subkey=1;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(mac_main_message,message_buf,message_len);
        for (mcntr=0;mcntr<16-(message_len%16);mcntr++)
        {
            if(mcntr==0)///first bit
            {mac_main_message[((message_len/16)*16)+((message_len%16))]=0x80;}
            else
            {mac_main_message[((message_len/16)*16)+((message_len%16))+mcntr]=0x0;}            
        }
        active_subkey=2;
    }

        
    
    ////cbc encryption base on plot


         if((message_len%16)==0)
         { taqsim_len=(message_len/16);}
         else
         { taqsim_len=(message_len/16)+1;}
         
    for(mcntr=0; mcntr< taqsim_len-1;mcntr++)///((message_len/16)+(message_len%16))
    {
        if(mcntr==0)
        {   //FIRST BLOCK
            memcpy(mac_main_k,(mac_main_message),16);
            aes_encrypt_128(hash_key_me,mac_main_k,mac_iv_k);   
        }
        else
        {   //sec...end BLOCK
            memcpy(mac_main_k,(mac_main_message+(16*mcntr)),16);
            xor_state2(mac_xor_k,mac_iv_k,mac_main_k,16);
            aes_encrypt_128(hash_key_me,mac_xor_k,mac_iv_k);  
        }
    }
    
 
    memcpy(mac_main_k,(mac_main_message+((taqsim_len-1)*16)),16); 

    xor_state2(mac_xor_k,mac_iv_k,mac_main_k,16);
    if(active_subkey==1)
    {xor_state2(mac_xor_k_final,mac_xor_k,k1_subkey,16);}
    else if(active_subkey==2)
    {xor_state2(mac_xor_k_final,mac_xor_k,k2_subkey,16);}
    aes_encrypt_128(hash_key_me,mac_xor_k_final,mac_tag); 
    
    ///debug
//    for(mcntr=0 ;mcntr <16;mcntr++)
//    {
//        SendChar4(k1_subkey[mcntr]);
//    }
//        for(mcntr=0 ;mcntr <16;mcntr++)
//    {
//        SendChar4(k2_subkey[mcntr]);
//    }
    memcpy(output_Tag,mac_tag,16);
//    for(mcntr=0 ;mcntr <16;mcntr++)
//    {
//        SendChar4(mac_tag[mcntr]);
//    }
 
}
```

The code above works, but it can't be translated to Pascal.

Comment: What do you mean with "*... it can't be translated to pascal*"? Why not?

Comment: @TomBrunberg some functions like `aes_key_schedule_128` and `aes_encrypt_128` or `xor_state2` and ... are in code i dont have idea what thay do!

Comment: How about at least linking to where you found it? (Edit your question, don't add comments.)

Comment: @roozgar There are plenty of encryption libraries available for Delphi which support AES.

Comment: @RemyLebeau after lots of try with different libraries i can't create `cmac` tag yet, `indy` , `openssl` , `DCPcrypt2` ,all have `hmac` but dont have anything for `cmac`

Comment: @roozgar perhaps, but they do have things for AES, which is the piece you are missing if you translate that C code to Pascal.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes i done the aes part.but the result of any function i used for key schedule in delphi is different of `aes_key_schedule_128` do you know how can i do key keyschedule in delphi?

Comment: @roozgar no, I do not